In a GLM model with a gamma log link, how to interpret a negative coefficent of a dummy variable with a continuous response?
I am a little confused with how to interpret a negative coefficient in a GLM model using the Gamma family with  a  log link.
My response variable is continuous (with no zeros) and right skewed and represents per-capita energy use. Because of its distribution I am using a gamma with a log link.  I have a binary independent variable whose coefficient is negative. Here is my R code:
m5 <- glm(dkw_cap ~ REF_YES + per_homeown + per_belowpov + per_bach, data = df2, family = Gamma(link='log'))
summary(m5)

Call:
glm(formula = dkw_cap ~ ST_YES + per_homeown + per_belowpov + 
    per_bach, family = Gamma(link = "log"), data = df2)

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   -4.9945     1.4115  -3.538 0.000446 ***
ST_YES       -0.8079     0.3392  -2.382 0.017665 *  
per_homeown    4.9634     1.4943   3.322 0.000971 ***
per_belowpov  -2.3498     3.1457  -0.747 0.455461    
per_bach      -2.7391     1.9371  -1.414 0.158079    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Gamma family taken to be 9.598368)

    Null deviance: 995.64  on 436  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 710.41  on 432  degrees of freedom
AIC: -1597

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 25

My confusion is how to interpret the ST_YES coefficient as it pertains to the response variable.
I had read that multiplying the exponents of the intercept and the coefficient addresses the log transformation issue.
exp(-4.9945) * exp(-0.8079)
[1] 0.003020297

Let's say the ST_YES is coded as 1=street with trees, 0= street without trees.
How do I interpret this relationship?

Have you seen this?

This question is similar and has an accepted answer. But, briefly, what is $e^0$? It's 1.
If you had some binary variable with a $\beta$ of 0, then it is associated with zero difference in the mean of the DV. If $\beta > 0$, then the coefficient is associated with a multiplicatively higher mean - $e^{0.5}$ is over 1. You just exponentiate the beta to get the multiplier. If you're familiar with epidemiology, this is like a relative risk.
You didn't ask, but consider the coefficients like per_homeown. Are they coded as percentage points, so the variable has a range of 0-100? Or are they coded as fractions, so the variable has a range of 0-1?
$e^{4.9634} \approx 143$, which seems like a large change in the DV if the home ownership rate goes up by one percentage point. You may be meaning that the average of the DV increases a bit over 143-fold if the home ownership rate goes up by one hundred percentage points, which seems like a bigger change than your average census tract or whatever might undergo. Basically, take care how you have coded variables that are fractions.

Thanks for the heads up regarding the per_homeown.  So in terms of the ST_YES,  am I right to say that observations with streets with trees (ST_YES=1)  are expected to have 0.003 higher value of dkw_cap than those where ST_YES = 0?
